# Django tests Get created object against client.post()

Tags: python, django, testing

I have created a test which which would sent a post request to a url and the method called against that request makes few objects, my question is how do i get these created objects ?

```
def test_post(self):
    response = self.c.post('/url/', {'name' : 'postname', 'content' : 'abc'})
```

while my view logic looks something like

```
Class MakePost():
  def makePost(self, request, data):
     object = Class()
     object2 = AnotherClass()
     return object
  def get_success_url(self, request, user):
     return '/post/'
```

Comment: This is really unclear. The client will get whatever is returned by the API endpoint.

Comment: yea well i am getting the /post/ page but i want those created objects say "object" and "object2" in this case

Comment: You still need to be more clear. What are those objects? Where are they stored? Why do you want to get them? Maybe you should show some real code.

Comment: say object is categories for that post being processed and object2 is a post in itself being made by data provided like name of post and content of post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your created objects in you test like:

```
def test_post(self):
    response = self.c.post('/url/', {'name' : 'postname', 'content' : 'abc'})
    # assume the above call has created an Post and a Category objects. Let's check them out.
    category = Category.objects.get(name='category')
    post = Post.objects.get(name='postname')
    self.assertEqual(post.content, 'abc')
    self.assertEqual(post.category, category)
```

As your database is cleaned before every `test_*` method and contains no objects (except fixtures if you use any), there would be only one object with that name.